# R Measuring Interaction of Independant Variables in mboost

Tags: r, regression

I have been using `mboost` lately to take large sets of independent variables and to identify the useful predictors.  For example:

```
library(mboost)
xx=glmboost(data=mtcars,mpg~.)
```

As I understand it, the algorithm treats each dependent variable separately and tries to, through a gradient process, identify the important predictors.

But maybe there's some complicated interaction.  Possibly the effect of `cyl` on `mpg` is much less important as `wt` increases.  That might make intuitive sense.  A small car with 12 cyl is some kind of sports car and the driver of inefficient mpg at that point is the cyl.  But for a truck it's really the weight that is the driver of low mpg.

How do you handle the (possibly non-linear) interaction effects of variables when using mboost or other boosting algorithms?

I don't want to go down the path to NN or Forest models that can't be explained.  Is there a better way to handle this?

I really like the boosting approach - the papers on it are readable and the results seem comprehendible to a normal human being.  But it seems like you will get a less than perfect fit when you have interaction.

Thanks, Josh

Comment: Please confirm (perhaps elaborate?) that this is a concrete implementation question and not a methodological.

Comment: Well, I guess a little of each.  Maybe I'm approaching it wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the GBM or XGBoost packages? Are you required to use a GLM for the base learner? Trees are very flexible.

Comment: I was looking at some of the tree libraries and I didn't see anything that would combine a few levels of trees with something like mboost.  It seems that either you are all-in on trees or all-in on mboost.  My hesitancy with trees is that an all-tree model doesn't seem to work for non-categorization tasks.  At least not in a way that I can understand.  And then the tree library makes many nodes so it becomes incomprehensible.  I'm happy to hear otherwise if there's a better way.

Comment: And no requirement for a linear base learner but I just thought easier to start with before moving on to gamboost.

Comment: The GBM package has a var.monotone argument that can enforce monotonic splits. This is a step closer to a simpler interpretation. May be worth  checking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell the formula to consider all 2-way interactions like so:

```
library(mboost)
xx=glmboost(data=mtcars,mpg~.*.)

> xx

     Generalized Linear Models Fitted via Gradient Boosting

Call:
glmboost.formula(formula = mpg ~ . * ., data = mtcars)


     Squared Error (Regression) 

Loss function: (y - f)^2 


Number of boosting iterations: mstop = 100 
Step size:  0.1 
Offset:  20.09062 

Coefficients: 
  (Intercept)            wt        cyl:wt       disp:am       hp:drat       hp:qsec         hp:vs       drat:wt 
 5.4682615930 -0.7166140321 -0.1962980466 -0.0016453733 -0.0002571366 -0.0010587752 -0.0099340044 -0.0889320001 
    drat:qsec     drat:carb     qsec:gear     qsec:carb         vs:am 
 0.0332626627 -0.0333151844  0.0450134161 -0.0026624244  3.1278334260 
attr(,"offset")
[1] 20.09062
```

Comment: You might want to consider centering the variables before doing this to reduce potential  problems with collinearity.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew it had to be something simple.  Now, once you have the two way interactions, how does it work?    Like in `cyl:wt`, what does that mean from a formulaic perspective?  If `cyl` is 6 and `wt` is 3000, what does the -1.19629 multiply by when actually using the formula?

Comment: As far as center, I thought from the docs that the default boost control tell the lib to center the data for you, is that not correct?

Comment: Yes, but it brings everything back to the normal scale in the coefficients.

Comment: Please use e.g. `coef(xx)` to extract the coefficients (which can be interpreted as regular coefficients from an interaction model) and `predict(xx, newdata = data.frame( *some_new_data* ))` to make predictions. Please also refer to relevant tutorials (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mboost/vignettes/mboost_tutorial.pdf; also available as vignette!) for more details on mboost.

Finally, please note that you need to tune your model before interpreting the results.